# Cannot remap key in evil-normal-state-map

Tags: key-bindings, evil, spacemacs

I'm trying

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "o") nil)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "o") 'evil-end-of-line)
```

but the key remains bound to `evil-open-below`.

FWIW I'm using `spacemacs` on emacs 24.5.1

Comment: Does this happen only for this key?  Is it any different when used in an Emacs session (as opposed to in your init file)?

Comment: It happens with other keys as well. It does work when I evaluate it in a session! FWIW all my bindings are done in user-config

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong in your init file :>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change definitions inside a keymap, it must be available at the time you access it.  In this case it would happen after Evil has been loaded which unless you've explicitly done that before that snippet will not be the case.  The cleanest way of deferring it until that point would be using `with-eval-after-load`:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "o") 'evil-end-of-line))
```

Comment: Cheers, that did the trick!